# Is there a jQuery equivalent to ASP.NET AJAX's Sys.UI.Behavior?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, behavior

I created a javascript class to refer to certain elements on the page.
Now I want to know how to associate it with that DOM element.

**Example:**

HTML

```
<div id="header"></div>
```

Then I have a class called header where I could call functions like:

JAVASCRIPT:

```
header.ShowText('Story 1');
header.HighlightText();
header.AddSubheader('Subheader');
```

etc...

Comment: Have you looked into knockout.js? Yours would be a prime scenario for data binding a JavaScript view model to your DOM element(s).

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a class to attach to DOM elements. jQuery does that for you.

Examples:

```
header.ShowText('Story 1');
```

is

```
$('header').html('Story 1');
```

.

```
header.HighlightText();
```

is

```
$('header').addClass('highlighttextstyle');
```

You can chain them, add effects, etc.

If you need a brief jQuery course, there was a good one recently: http://learnjquery.tutsplus.com/